# When to use CompletableFuture#thenApply(..) over thenApplyAsync(..)?

Tags: java, completable-future

In context of `CompletableFuture` I understand that `thenApply(..)` may use the current thread and may use the a pre-defined executor (e.g. ForkJoinPool) while `thenApplyAsync(..)` ensures that the pre-defined executor will be always used.

Far as I see the `thenApplyAsync(..)` seems be more "reliable" as it never blocks the current thread while `thenApply(..)` might be a surprise.

My question: Which example/scenario would be valid to use `thenApply(..)` rather than `thenApplyAsync(..)`?

Thanks, Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `thenApplyAsync` would use some excecutor. This means that some Runnable object must be created and put in the executor's queue. If the function you want to execute after the complethion of this  `CompletableFuture` is very simple, then invoking this method directly may be more efficient than creating envelope Runnable.